# How to apply path compression to Multi-Bit Trie

Tags: data-structures, trees, search-trees

Reading a bit about the subject of Multi-Bit tries and IP matching in:

> High Performance Switches and Routers H. Jonathan Chao, Bin Liu. Page 33
>
> Network Routing: Algorithms, Protocols, and Architectures (The Morgan Kaufmann Series in Networking) April 12, 2007
>   by Deepankar Medhi. Page 507.

And they both mention path compression but they do not explain how to apply path compression to Multi-Bit tries (they only mention that this could be done).

I would like to understand how one would path compress (not level compress) a $k$-Bit trie? What would be the the asymptotic number of nodes given $N$ entries and $w$ width addresses?